# laravel is there a way to make 3 tables, one table belongs to 2 different tables, with one to one relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, one-to-one

laravel is there a way to make, one to one relationship, one table belongs to two different tables one to one relationship.

i'm trying to model, a laravel based project, that is voting for ministers.

these are my three models.

members migration. ex: members is working as users for authentication

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('members', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('username');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

2.ministers migration file

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('ministers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->mediumText('description');
            $table->string('image')->default('no-image.jpg');
            $table->unsignedInteger('votes')->default('0');
            $table->boolean('status')->default('0');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

3.voters migration file

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('voters', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('phone');
            $table->enum('education', ['primary', 'intermediate', 'high-school', 'university' ] )->nullable(false)->default('primary');
            $table->string('country');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('minister_id');
            $table->foreign('minister_id')->references('id')->on('ministers');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('member_id');
            $table->foreign('member_id')->references('id')->on('members');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

this voters migration belongs to member and minister, and mister associates one voter, user associates to one voter.

so is this correct way to model, a system like this. which i want every registered member, fill out voting form, which selects a drop down field of the minister to be voted for. and save that form creating a new instance of voter. What i want also is two increment by one minister votes field when ever a new instance of voter is created.

Comment: Sounds good if you need all that information

Comment: @TymurValiiev is there a better way you would like to recommend? how cound i also make the voting duration in 15 days, when 15 days is over to stop the voting. etc.

Comment: If there is a better way, you will figure it out when you need it. 
Don't overthink what you're doing. 
This works, and this works well for what you have told us. When you will have other need, you may need other solution (or you may not).
Overall looks good to me and you probably can stick with that for quite a long time

Comment: Add another table of votings, which represent what people are voting for, create dates in it and you are done :)